# Google line chart not appearing in PDF file

Tags: laravel, pdf, google-visualization

I am trying to create a line chart and display it in PDF through blade file in Laravel. By using https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js

But somehow the chart not appearing in the pdf but also followed the tutorial well. Maybe i need some help on how to fix this .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['location', 'pointer'],


            @php
                foreach ($last as $l) {
                    echo "['" . $l->location . "', '" . $l->pointer . "'],";
                }
            @endphp

        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'testing chart',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('google'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how are you generating the pdf files, dompdf?

Comment: @andresdevr yes using dompdf

Comment: the chart is drawn asynchronously, which means it will not be immediately available when the page loads and you're dompdf function runs. another approach might be to build the page and draw the chart, then listen for the chart's ready event in JavaScript, at which point you could use AJAX to send an image of the chart (`chart.getImageURI()`) back to the server and then build the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```html
@php
foreach ($last as $l) {
    echo "['" . $l->location . "', " . $l->pointer . "],";
}
@endphp
```

you cannot put string to Y axis